# Get the element underneath the dropped element with jquery ui droppable and elementFromPoint

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am on IE 11 and I use jquery ui droppable/draggable.

When I drop an element I want to get the element underneath the dropped element.

What I get at the moment as targetElement is the element I drop...

Why?

I have read everywhere that in the drop event I get the element underneath the dropped element, but I get the dropped element...

```
    $("#container").droppable({
        accept: ".droppableElements",
        activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
        drop: function (event, ui) {


var targetElement = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
ui.draggable.detach().insertBefore(targetElement );

        }
    });
```

Comment: Provide your HTML & CSS, maybe in a convenient [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)..

Comment: Can not rip my production code here. But I found a solution it "seems" by setting all z-index of the current elements to 10000 + i that way I get the element beneath! But as the element beneath consist of multiple divs I use jquery with class selector to get the correct container!

Comment: Good one! Provide it as an answer to your own question and accept it!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution it "seems" by setting all z-index of the current elements on the droppable container to **z-index: 10000** + i that way I get the element beneath!

Starting from the element beneath - as it consists of multiple divs -  I did this to get the parent element with a certain class:

var parent = $(targetElementBeneathDroppedElement).closest('.refOptionItem')[0];

I was happy! :-)